# What svm python modules use gpu?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu, svm

I wonder what svm python modules use gpu accelerating.

Does `libsvm` or `scikit-svm` use `gpu`?

How can I use gpu accelerating with svm?

Comment: NVIDIA RAPIDS might support SVM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a [GPU-accelerated LIBSVM](https://mklab.iti.gr/results/gpu-accelerated-libsvm/) that uses the CUDA framework.

`scikit-svm` will never support GPU. From the [FAQ](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html):

> Will you add GPU support?
>
> > No, or at least not in the near future. The main reason is that GPU support will introduce many software dependencies and introduce platform specific issues. scikit-learn is designed to be easy to install on a wide variety of platforms. Outside of neural networks, GPUs don’t play a large role in machine learning today, and much larger gains in speed can often be achieved by a careful choice of algorithms.

Comment: Is it possible to be used in python?

Comment: Well, you can always use some wrapper around command line execution saving arrays as files and then calling the `gpu-libsvm` through `Popen` or something.

Comment: Link is dead :'(

Answer (score 10):

[ThunderSVM](https://github.com/Xtra-Computing/thundersvm) A Fast SVM Library on GPUs and CPUs

[image]

It also provides a scikit-learn [Python interface](https://github.com/Xtra-Computing/thundersvm/tree/master/python)